# How to change the java file icon in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

How to change the java file icon in intellij idea?
[Please click here to see full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUyqm.png)

I want to change the java file type icon to how it looks in the above picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to create the [**Custom UI Theme**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes.html) plugin for the IntelliJ platform and install it into the IDE.

The default IntelliJ Platform UI icons can be replaced by custom icons. The file format for icons is SVG. The [JetBrains Platform UI Guideline for Icons](https://jetbrains.design/intellij/principles/icons/) has detailed specifications for icons.

An icon replacement is described within the `icon {}` section of a Theme description file. Note that icon replacement key-value pairs appear outside of the `ColorPalette` section.

See [Custom icons](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-customize.html#custom-icons) section of the Plugins Development guide.